# Calling Batch file Java program

Tags: java, batch-file, functional-programming

I am trying to call a bat file from my Java function. Looks like some issue in the way I am calling the bat file. The batch file is not called from the method. Any help would be appreciated.

```
private static void Run_Main() throws InterruptedException, SQLException, IOException {
    int set_value=0;
    while ((set_value=Find_Flag()) !=0){
        System.out.println("Set_Value"+set_value);  
        System.out.println("Staging load is not completed ..Revisiting after 15 minutes....");
        Thread.sleep(900000);
        set_value=Find_Flag();
    }
    System.out.println("Staging load is Completed and launching Proudction Load now");
    //Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "cmd.exe", "/c", "C:/exec/DW_Init_Load.bat" } );
    String filePath = "C:/exec/DW_Init_Load.bat";
    try {

        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(filePath);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    System.out.println("Production Load is finished");
}
```

I am interested to know what is the mistake I have made in the code

Comment: Post the exception stack trace if any exception is present. Or post your stdout.

Comment: How can you tell it is not running? Errors? Logs?

Comment: You aren't waiting for the `Process` to complete; `p.waitFor();`

Comment: are you sure bat file exists? to make sure use : try{ File file = new File(filePath); if ( file.exists() ) { ...run process...} } catch(..)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch : p.waitFor() helped me to solve the issue. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Adding p.waitFor() helped me solve this issues. Initially the block is not waiting for the process to complete.